# Even if I've changed the apiVersion of ingress in helm, I got error: unable to recognize "" no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

**Environment**

1. K8s

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.15", GitCommit:"1d79bc3bcccfba7466c44cc2055d6e7442e140ea", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-09-21T12:18:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24+", GitVersion:"v1.24.8-eks-ffeb93d", GitCommit:"abb98ec0631dfe573ec5eae40dc48fd8f2017424", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-11-29T18:45:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.18.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
WARNING: version difference between client (1.22) and server (1.24) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

2. apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
```

**Description**

After changed the apiVersion, I got an error

```
current release manifest contains removed kubernetes api(s) for this kubernetes version and it is therefore unable to build the kubernetes objects for performing the diff. error from kubernetes: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1"
```

There are two questions confused me

1. Even if I've changed the apiVersion to "networking.k8s.io/v1", it still match api by "extensions/v1"
2. It's hard to know which field is needed to be modified because it's blank.

Below is my template file

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Namespace }}-ingress
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: {{ .Values.listenPorts | toJson | quote }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: {{ .Values.certificateArn }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /health-check
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: "30"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds: "5"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-Ext-2018-06"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: deletion_protection.enabled={{ .Values.deleteProtection }},access_logs.s3.enabled={{ .Values.enabledAccessLog }},access_logs.s3.bucket=alb-access-log-s3-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
    # maintenance mode - api-playback # 
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.api-playback-maintenance-rule-1 : {{ .Values.maintenanceIpAddress1 | toJson | quote }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.api-playback-maintenance-rule-2 : {{ .Values.maintenanceIpAddress2 | toJson | quote }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.api-playback-maintenance-rule-3 : {{ .Values.maintenanceIpAddress3 | toJson | quote }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.api-playback-maintenance-rule-1 : {{ .Values.playbackMaintenanceAnnotationCode  | toJson | quote }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.api-playback-maintenance-rule-2 : {{ .Values.playbackMaintenanceAnnotationCode  | toJson | quote }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.api-playback-maintenance-rule-3 : {{ .Values.playbackMaintenanceAnnotationCode  | toJson | quote }}
    
    # maintenance mode - api-cms #
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.api-cms-maintenance-rule-1 : {{ .Values.maintenanceIpAddress1 | toJson | quote }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.api-cms-maintenance-rule-2 : {{ .Values.maintenanceIpAddress2 | toJson | quote }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.api-cms-maintenance-rule-3 : {{ .Values.maintenanceIpAddress3 | toJson | quote }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.api-cms-maintenance-rule-1 : {{ .Values.cmsMaintenanceAnnotationCode  | toJson | quote  }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.api-cms-maintenance-rule-2 : {{ .Values.cmsMaintenanceAnnotationCode  | toJson | quote  }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.api-cms-maintenance-rule-3 : {{ .Values.cmsMaintenanceAnnotationCode  | toJson | quote }}

    # maintenance mode - api-client #

    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.api-client-maintenance-rule-1 : {{ .Values.maintenanceIpAddress1 | toJson | quote }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.api-client-maintenance-rule-2 : {{ .Values.maintenanceIpAddress2 | toJson | quote }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.api-client-maintenance-rule-3 : {{ .Values.maintenanceIpAddress3 | toJson | quote }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.api-client-maintenance-rule-1 : {{ .Values.clientMaintenanceAnnotationCode  | toJson | quote  }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.api-client-maintenance-rule-2 : {{ .Values.clientMaintenanceAnnotationCode  | toJson | quote  }}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.api-client-maintenance-rule-3 : {{ .Values.clientMaintenanceAnnotationCode  | toJson | quote }}

    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.maintenance-503: >
        {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"503","messageBody":"maintenance mode"}}

  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Release.Namespace }}-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}

spec:
  rules:
  # maintenance rules
  {{- $inMaintenanceMode := .Values.inMaintenanceMode  -}}
  {{- if $inMaintenanceMode }}
  {{- $dn := .Values.dn -}}
  {{- $hasDN := .Values.hasDN  -}}
  {{- range .Values.maintenanceRules }}
  {{- if $hasDN }}
  - host: {{ .hostPrefix }}.{{ $dn }}
    http:
  {{- else }}
  - http:
  {{- end }}
      paths:
      {{- range .paths }}
      - path: {{ .path }}
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .serviceName }}
            port:
              name: use-annotation
      {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  # if not inMaintenanceMode
  {{- else }}
  # default rules
  {{- $dn := .Values.dn -}}
  {{- $hasDN := .Values.hasDN  -}}
  {{- range .Values.rules }}
  {{- if $hasDN }}
  - host: {{ .hostPrefix }}.{{ $dn }}
    http:
  {{- else }}
  - http:
  {{- end }}
      paths:
      {{- range .paths }}
      - path: {{ .path }}
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .serviceName }}
            port: 
              number: {{ .servicePort }}
      {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

Deploy without the error

Comment: Please remove `terraform` tag since it's unrelated to your question

Answer (score 2):

It's due to API version mismatch, quick approach would be **uninstall** and **re-install** the **helm chart** for **Dev** environment if 2-3 min of **downtime** is fine for you.

You can use this **helm plugin** to get the idea about the **deprecated the API** : https://github.com/helm/helm-mapkubeapis

**Option 2** :

You can with suggested option to edit first the configmap/secret based on the backed

```
kubectl get secret -l owner=helm,status=deployed,name=<release_name> --namespace <release_namespace> | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v NAME

kubectl get secret <release_secret_name> -n <release_namespace> -o yaml > release.yaml

cp release.yaml release.bak

cat release.yaml | grep -oP '(?<=release: ).*' | base64 -d | base64 -d | gzip -d > release.data.decoded

cat release.data.decoded | gzip | base64 | base64

kubectl apply -f release.yaml -n <release_namespace>
```

Ref doc : https://helm.sh/docs/topics/kubernetes_apis/#updating-api-versions-of-a-release-manifest